# How I can enable the compass mode in Nutiteq?

Tags: java, android, nutiteq

How I can enable the compass mode in Nutiteq?

there is a method or I need to create by myselft the orientation system?

Comment: Have you read their documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have read their documentation, but I didn't find how to resolve this problem

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you just read the documentation and give up, or did you write some code in your efforts? Can we see that code?

Comment: I just read documentation and I don't know, can I enable compass or I should create my own? Final version Nutiteq Offline Maps on Google Play contains compass

Comment: There is no built-in orientation system, you need to use MapView.setRotation() or setMapRotation() since 2.3.0. It depends on use case and what sensors do you want to use for this - compass, magnetometer and GPS are all possible.

Answer (score 2):

I added now a CompassMapActivity.java sample to the https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/ AdvancedMap3D project. It rotates map based on compass, sets GPS location and adds a second person view 3D model. It is using Google sample OrientationManager code for compass reading smoothing, with raw data you will get very unstable picture.

We use it in Google Glass app, and it looks quite cool.

[image]